# I wanna change the orientation of my app while the app is runing (force certain pages portrait only and other landscape only)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I wanna force the orientation of some pages of my game app. Like, I want the orientation to be Portrait for the landing page, the options of my game, and the player selection, but I want to force the orientation to be landscape when the game begins... I tried using:

```dart
super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
])
```

and it does work on android, (except that it change the orientation 3 times before getting the right orientation...) But on iOS, it doesn't force the change... It only change when you turn the device and then it works and stays in landscape mode. I want the view to change even if I keep my phone in portrait...

Does anyone had the same issue and know how to fix it ?

I tried to put the `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` in the Widget build function but it didn't worked.

Comment: You can check this: https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new version of flutter, it works with the preferred orientation.

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13238) for Flutter on iOS. You can either wait for the release or switch to the newest Flutter version by running command `flutter channel master`. But be careful - master branch isn't stable enough to use in production.

Comment: And with the newest version, the orientation is working with iOS too ?

Comment: @SimonB At least it should be working. According to the issue they merged the fix 10 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

This worked for me!